# Websocket Load Testing

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing

We have a Websocket server which I have to load test. The test case is as follows:

1. Maximum number of connections possible
2. Each connections should be sending 1 message/second

Tools I have tried:

1. Phantom JS (Unsuccessful)
2. Apache JMeter (Partially successfully): I was able to simulate simultaneous connections. For each connection a separate thread is created. But I am only able to send one message after connecting using the plugin https://github.com/kawasima/jmeter-websocket/ the thread just remains stagnant after send that one message. I cannot create a separate thread group for sending messages as I wish to test a situation where communication takes place via the existing Websocket only. I might be missing some configuration or a rare plugin which allows me to recreate my test case.
3. NeoLoad 4.2: This is the exact tool I was looking for. It allows me to perfectly create my test case BUT my company is not ready to invest in any testing tool(Forget about having a testing team either). And due to trial limitations, I am only able to simulate 10 users.

Please suggest/advice with any possible tool or plugin which will help me.

**EDIT:**

Here is how I managed it.

```
public class Tester {

    static int i;
    int numberOfConnections = 300; //number of simultaneous connections.

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String channel = "111";

        for (i = 0; i < numberOfConnections; i++) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            final CUstomWebsocketClientWrapper client = new CUstomWebsocketClientWrapper("http://162.243.235.172:8080", "demo", "demo");
                            client.createConnection(channel + i); //Open the connection

                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);

                            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    while (true) {
                                        try {
                                            client.push(channel + i, "Message" + i); //Send message
                                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); //Change message sending rate here.
                                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                            Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();

                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will create clients sending messages at the defined rate. Make sure you have loads of RAM or you'll end up with an out of memory error. And after each test you will have to restart Tomcat/Jetty so the threads are destroyed. This is not the ideal or memory efficient way but this is the only method that works for free.

Comment: How to check the response time while performing load testing in websocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I used a .net websocket client library, however .net 4.5 has support for websockets: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617611/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-1

I am sure there are other libraries in java or other languages that also allow you to interact with a WebSocket, but I am less familiar with them.  Once you find a library, you can create the calls to make the connection and then send any additional requests to the WebSocket.

You could then either use a tool such as Jmeter through it's support of executing junit tests, or write some code to spawn threads and send requests yourself.

What I ended up writing through the use of the .net WebSocket library was a functional automation framework for the WebSocket that was extended to also perform load and stress tests.  All of the tests were executed through nunit, and our framework handled all of the thread management.  I'm not sure what your or your team's skill set is, but if you have a developer familiar with writing a multi-threaded app, it isn't so bad to write it from scratch.  The nice thing about this approach is that you can easily use it for functional automated tests.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing. I am the developer and tester both. There are Websocket libraries in Java and I am using this https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync But the program fails to create a consistent test scenario. You are right, I need to look more into multi-threading properly.

Comment: At the time of my answer, it was good, but the answer from Dmitri is now a much simpler route to take.

Answer (score 4):

There is a newer plugin for JMeter which is fully RFC 6455 compliant and allows re-using same TCP session for multiple duplex requests.

- [JMeter WebSocket Sampler by Maciej Zaleski](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter) - download from Releases page
- [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) - how-to guide

Comment: That's an amazing step by step guide! I'll keep it marked for the future. For now, I have written a multi-threaded program which servers just fine. :)

Comment: @GauravBhor Can you please share your code if it is just a test suite?

Comment: @Dmitri T, I tried this tutorial, my problem as I commented there that each Thread/User is actually generating 9-10 native JVM threads, do you have any advices?

Comment: I guess it worth asking plugin developer, perhaps underlying Jetty implementation may be the cause as looking into the plugin code I don't see anything spawning 9-10 threads.

Comment: @Montaro I've edited my question to include the code for you. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3):

You may use websocket client library for any popular language (e.g. java or python).
For your test scenario it will be more suitable way of testing, rather than try to find some test tools.

Also, I'd advise to use 'select' or 'poll' instead of threading, because it scales better, especially if you need more than 10K connections.
It took about a couple of hours for me to create simple test suite using python asyncore library.

Comment: Alright. I'm not sure in which context are you saying 'select' or 'poll'. Could you please explain?

Comment: I was talking about I/O multiplexing. The couple of low level functions are 'select' and 'poll'.

Comment: In Java, that'd refer to the NIO library with socket channels

Answer (score 2):

What can I see from your code is that at least you generate 600 native JVM thread to simulate 300 connections only which is a small number, I also doubt that the library you are using CUstomWebsocketClientWrapper creates extra threads per each connection which will end up with super inefficient tool to do the job.

I tried the recipe here http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter which is different from your experience since it depends on a different Websocket JMeter Sampler plugin. The problem as I mentioned earlier was that the plugin internally creates ~10 threads per user which is inefficient for me to simulate 60K from a single box

What I'm trying right now is using the **thor** https://www.npmjs.org/package/thor, it seems very light weight I used it to simulate 10K concurrent connection so far.

Comment: Do you just want concurrent users or concurrent active users? I know it is not memory efficient. But creating 2 threads instead of 10 is better. Also, I had to simulate using different terminals. Creating 60k threads from one machine will freeze your jvm. Please try distribution..

Comment: Of course I will use distribution to simulate 100K concurrent users, but with your algorithm, how many machines you need to achieve this number; you need 200 machine to simulate 60K!, Did I get it right?

Comment: I could simulate 700-800 connections from one terminal. 4 gigs of RAM each. Also, how much RAM does your server have? If you are considering paid solutions, Neo Load is the best for this task.

Comment: I executed this on my machine:

`arefaey@arefaey-MacBook-Pro ~> thor -C 60000 --amount 60000 ws://localhost:9000 -P 13 --masked -W 4`

This spawns 4 node workers and the maximum memory footprint for all node processes was almost 1GB

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success with https://testable.io. It lets you test websockets by writing a Node.js script and then replaying it at scale and giving you plenty of metrics (see [WebSocket Performance Testing in 4 Simple Steps](http://blog.testable.io/post/137725366323/websocket-performance-testing-in-4-simple-steps) from Testable Blog). Not sure if the free tier would generate enough load for you, but something to try out potentially.